# How do I enforce constraints on QML properties

Tags: qml

Say I have a reusable component:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Control {
    id: root

    property int range
    property int value

// ... implementation...

}
```

I would like to constrain `range` to be 1 or higher, and `value` to be between 0 and `range-1` inclusive. Implementing this in Javascript might look like:

```
Control {
    id: root

    property int range
    property int value

    onValueChanged: {
        value = Math.min(Math.max(0, value), range-1);
    }

    onRangeChanged: {
        range = Math.max(value, 1);
        value = Math.min(Math.max(0, value), range-1);
    }

// ...
```

However, this will break any binding that another component might make when it uses mine.

How can I enforce property constraints (a) without breaking bindings, and (b) without repeating myself in every change handler?

Answer (score 3):

Write the property's getters and setters in C++. See the [integrating QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) documentation for details.

Even Qt Quick Controls 1 (where almost every API is in QML) used a C++ class for managing its ranges:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qquickrangemodel_p.h

If you really have to do it in QML, I would suggest having one property that is modifiable and "public" (e.g. `value`) and another that is `readonly` and "private" (e.g. `_value`) so that you use declarative code for it and not break any bindings:

```
readonly property int _value: Math.min(Math.max(0, value), range - 1);
```

Comment: Hmm, this may also be the best answer to another question I asked: [How do I have declarative, bidirectional bindings involving QML MouseAreas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898364/how-do-i-have-declarative-bidirectional-bindings-involving-qml-mouseareas).